# How to solve error for require(URL-metadata) in angular 8 metadata

Tags: html, css, angular

> just start to using angular 8 and I want to fetch metadata from the URL ...   when enter any URL into the input field ,it has to pull meta data from it 
>   am using  url-metadata npm in angular
>   this is the basic usage using in angular when executing code throwing error for require in angular 8

```
Then in your project file (from example/basic.js):

     const urlMetadata = require('url-metadata')
urlMetadata('http://amazon.com').then(
  function (metadata) { // success handler
    console.log(metadata)
  },
  function (error) { // failure handler
    console.log(error)
  })
```